# Cart Throb loses cart items in IE11

Tags: cartthrob, internetexplorer

A client has reported a strange error in a Cart Throb site where the items that are added to the basket aren't being saved. This is only happening in IE11.

Is there anything about cookies in IE11 that is *different* to previous versions of IE?

I tried logging into the site and this worked fine, retaining the cookies, but it still didn't hold items in the cart as I moved from page to page.

Anyone any thoughts?

EE2.7.2. Cart Throb 2.4

Comment: Can you add the {exp:cartthrob:debug_info} tag to your templates and take get a bit of insight as to what's happening? You should see an array of items in the cart.

Comment: Are you adding items to the cart via Ajax or some other javascript? Maybe this is failing in IE11 (which seems more likely to me)

Comment: Ah yes - forgot about that tag. I've added it to the cart page and another page to compare. The product is missing from the other page, but all the session data is identical. We're not using Ajax or anything fancy here, its just as you pass from 1 page to the next it loses the product data.

Comment: And cookies aren't blocked?

Comment: Nope (I'm using Browserstack but the client has reported it too), and I can log in to the site and My Account areas.

Comment: Have you tried changing the "Fingerprinting Method" on the Settings->General tab?

Comment: Good call, but no, still not working. Have tried changing to IP only, User Agent Only and HTTP_ACCEPT etc. Tried disabling the fingerprinting altogether and couldn't add anything to the cart at all then. Also, there's no jump from a www to non-www or vice versa - working fine everywhere else.

Comment: So I've been doing some more testing. Changing the user agent string in IE retains the cart information. Have also checked our other Cart Throb sites and they don't have the problem. Still no nearer finding the issue :-(

Comment: Still exploring this one but no luck so far. Have updated CT to 2.5 and some tags in the cart_items_info tag stopped outputting values (taxes) and same issue in IE. Rolled back to previous version and back to sq 1.

Comment: Having downgraded, I'm now seeing some really random behaviour (which might have been there before). Sometimes I can add an item to the cart and it will stick, when it does and I try and add a 2nd item to the cart, it won't add it. Hit the back button and try again, and it gets added. Continue shopping, then it drops the last added item.

Comment: I've seen an issue like this before, but with Safari. It related to cookie expirations. Out of curiosity, what happens if you try to update $expire in expressionengine/libraries/Functions.php to be $expire = time() + $expire + 31536000;? Just as a temporary test.

Comment: Thanks Matt. Tried this but still getting the same issue. I've a support call with Cart Throb today, so will update the post later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much frustration and searching around, I've finally tracked down the issue here. In between times I scheduled a support call with Cart Throb who were super helpful, so thank you to them for offering their input - it was their advice that set me off on the right track.

In the end however, it was an IE specific issue related to [Magic Zoom](http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoomplus/), a Javascript image zoom feature we'd added to the site. Although this states full compatibility with IE6+, and we've successfully used this before without any issues, it was, believe it or not, the stylesheet provided with it that was causing the problem.

Within the stylesheet were 3 references to `cursor` linking to a `.cur` file (also provided).

```
.MagicZoomPlus, .MagicZoomPlus:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: url(graphics/zoomin.cur), pointer;
  outline: 0 !important;
  font-size: 0 !important;
  line-height: 100% !important;
  direction: ltr;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I eventually noticed the cursor wasn't appearing in IE compared to sensible browsers, and removed the `.cur` references and *voila*! Items added to the cart and all working as expected. I can't say exactly why this was causing the problem, but I'm happy enough to see it working again and just set the cursor value to `move`.

Thanks for everyone's suggestions in the comments :-)

Comment: Custom cursor image doesn't work in all IEs?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419314/custom-cursor-image-doesnt-work-in-all-ies